# Can a MediaWiki moderator put a system message for each new user?

Tags: mediawiki

I am an admin on a MediaWiki instance where I can't edit the code, only act through the MediaWiki system itself.

Can I setup a notification for every new user? The notification should be seen until discarded by the user, never to appear again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see whether your MediaWiki installation has the extension [*DismissableSiteNotice*](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aDismissableSiteNotice) installed. You can check this by navigating to `Special:Version` of your wiki.

(If not installed, the notice would stay there without the ability to be discarded, so would not work for you -- you'd want to speak to the person who has access to the installation files.)

If you do have it, you can use a combination of `MediaWiki:Sitenotice` and `MediaWiki:Anonnotice`. (These are the things Wikipedia etc. use to display stuff like fundraisers on their pages.)

The two messages work in the following manner:

1. If the user is anonymous, `MediaWiki:Anonnotice` is displayed (if defined).
2. Otherwise, `MediaWiki:Sitenotice` is displayed (if defined).
3. Otherwise, the global notice in `$wgSiteNotice` is displayed (if defined).
4. Otherwise, no notice is displayed.

Therefore, you would want to set `MediaWiki:Sitenotice` to whatever message you want to show to the logged-in users; and set `MediaWiki:Anonnotice` to `<p></p>`. (The Anonnotice is necessary because if it's totally blank, it wouldn't be "defined" and thus the Sitenotice would be shown for anonymous users too.)